# Which Perl module can handle a variety of date formats containing unicode characters?

Tags: perl, datetime, unicode, timestamp

My requirement is parsing xml files which contains wide varieties of timestamps based on the locales at which they are written. They may contain Unicode characters in case of Chinese or Korean locales. I have to parse these timestamps and put then in a standard format something like `2009-11-26 12:40:54` to put them in a oracle database. Sometimes I may not even know the locale and yet I have to parse the timestamps.

I am looking for a module that automatically detects the timestamp format (including unicode characters for am and pm in their local language) and converts in to epoch time so that I can convert it back to what ever way I like to.

I have gone through similar questions in this forum. Few suggested DateFormat module, and Date::Parse module. The perl distribution I am using is 5.10 so [Date::Manip](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Date-Manip/) doesn't come as a core module. As I am supposed to use just the basic core modules and few CPAN modules(on request I cannot ask for all),

I request you to kindly suggest me a good module that suffices all my requirements.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what if I know the locale? does that simplify the problem?

Comment: You already accepted the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867550#2803497. Do go and ask to install this CPAN module, it does exactly what you need.

Comment: it doesn't support korean and japanese time stamps ...

Comment: You are mistaken; in fact it does support them. http://p3rl.org/DateTime::Locale::ko http://p3rl.org/DateTime::Locale::ja

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse time stamps with Unicode characters in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867550/how-to-parse-time-stamps-with-unicode-characters-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

[DateTime::Locale](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime-Locale/) should do what you want.

Answer (score -1):

You might have a look at [Date::Manip](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Date-Manip/).  Don't know if it supports the languages you need but there is some UTF8 support in it.  In any case once you get the dates extracted it has a UnixDate method to easily output in whatever format you want.  Also resolves time zones.

Comment: Date::Manip hasn't been the right answer for some considerable number of years. Use DateTime instead.